# How to get the broadcast messages via Paramiko

Tags: python, linux, shell, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to get the broadcast messages via paramiko to ensure the action has completely performed. Something like this.

```py
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip, 22, user, passwd, timeout=180)
command = 'sleep 3; wall "The system will shutdown in 3 seconds."; sudo nohup shutdown -h now;'
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command, timeout=300)
if "The system will shutdown in 3 seconds." in stdout.read().encode('utf-8'):
    print "Command success!!"
else
    print "Command failure!!"
```

However, I always got an empty output. How can I get the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadcast messages are sent to interactive sessions only.

So you at least need to set `get_pty` parameter of `SSHClient.exec_command` to `True`.

Maybe you will even have to use a shell channel via `SSHClient.invoke_shell`.

---

*Though actually, I do not understand why you want to capture the broadcast. What does that "ensure"? Maybe something like checking `wall` exit code might be a more reliable approach.*

Comment: It’s because there will be numerous SSH connections to the machine, and some connections have to tell every connection to close before the system shutdown or reboot. The way to ensure the wall command is on other connections not the original one.